# Is there a proper, closed subset of [0,1] with Lesbegue unit measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In other words, if $F$ is a proper, closed subset of $[0,1]$, must $\mu(F) < 1$? What about in $[0,1]^n$?

My (frequently misguided) intuition wants to say "no", but I'm not sure how to approach a proof. Suggestions/hints/counterexamples welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct; the answer is "no". The complement of $F$ is open. If we pick a point $x\in[0,1]\setminus F$, there is an $\epsilon\gt0$ so that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap F=\emptyset$. An interval of at least $\min(1,\epsilon)$ must come from $[0,1]$, so $\mu(F)\le1-\min(1,\epsilon)\lt1$.

A similar argument works in $\mathbb{R}^n$ only we consider a ball of radius $\epsilon$ and at least $2^{-n}$ of its volume must come from the cube.

Comment: So you mean yes?

Comment: @LordSoth: It appears that robjohn is answering the question in the title, rather than in the body.

Comment: @LordSoth: the OP is correct, the answer is "no" :-)

Comment: @CameronBuie Haha, ok now I got it. I was looking for a secret contradiction in the proof (so that $\mu(\mathcal{F})$ will turn out to be $1$ somehow) :)

Comment: @robjohn Thanks, the complement being open (and non-empty) in [0,1] was the key I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** any proper closed subset of $[0,1]$ can be obtained by subtracting a non-empty open set.